# Where can I find simple integration problems (and other computational exercises) involving special functions?

Tags: special-functions, self-learning, education

Working lots of computational exercises in my pre-calculus and calculus classes has given me a great deal of intuition in dealing with elementary functions. Thanks to these years of practice, I can readily manipulate, differentiate, and (in simple cases) integrate expressions involving sines, cosines, exponentials, and logarithms.

However, I find myself at a loss when I need to perform these operations on expressions involving special functions (e.g. $\Gamma(z)$, $J_n(z)$, $\operatorname{Si}(z)$, $\operatorname{Ai}(z)$, $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$). I can easily look up the relevant definitions and identities online, but reading about them is no substitute for working with them. Where can I find some elementary computational exercises (e.g. integration problems) involving these functions?

Answer (score 2):

Whittaker and Watson's A Course of Modern Analysis is a standard source for these types of problems.